# Decomposition of edges of eulerian graph into maximum number of cycles

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I'm interested in the following problem.

Given an eulerian graph $G=(V,E)$, we are to find a partition of its edges $C_1, C_2, \ldots, C_k$ ($\cup_i C_i=E$ and $i \neq j \leftrightarrow C_i \cap C_j = \varnothing$), such that each $C_i$ forms a simple cycle in $G$ and $k$ is maximum possible.

In other words, we are to cover every edge of an eulerian graph with a maximum number of edge-disjoint simple cycles.

Is this problem well-known? Is there a known approach to solve it?

Comment: Is the graph directed or undirected?

Answer (score 2):

A special case of your problem - checking if there is an edge-partition of the graph into triangles - is shown to be NP-complete in [this paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0210054), where it is the $n=3$ case of the more general problem of edge-partitioning a graph into copies of $K_n$.

(If such an edge-partition exists, then it's definitely the best solution: any other way to partition the graph into cycles will use fewer cycles. So in some cases, solving your problem is at least as hard as solving the triangle edge-partition problem.)

This doesn't say much about how to solve the problem, but it does say that we shouldn't look for a polynomial-time algorithm. Maybe some sort of standard dealing-with-brute-force-search approaches such as branch-and-bound would work.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by this answer: the question assumes that the input graph is Eulerian, but the paper you mention does not talk about this assumption. Is your point that the graphs used in the proofs of that paper are in fact Eulerian?

Comment: @a3nm The paper does not need to mention the assumption; if we're asking the question "does $G$ have a $K_3$-decomposition?" then $G$ must be Eulerian for it to be a nontrivial question. (All graphs with a $K_3$-decomposition, or any other cycle decomposition, are Eulerian.) Therefore, without checking, we can be certain that the NP-completeness construction gives Eulerian graphs (and in the general case of $K_n$-decomposition, graphs in which every vertex degree is divisible by $n-1$).

Comment: Oh, of course, thanks! (Well, up to the subtlety that a Eulerian graph $G$ must be connected, whereas a graph with a $K_3$-decomposition may not be -- but of course that makes no difference.)